# "You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression" while using ansible "win_shell" module

Tags: powershell, ansible

I am using ansible win_shell module to run below commands on windows host but getting error "You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression"

cmd:-

```
  - name: Get ASG Instance id
    win_shell: |
      $ASG=(Get-ASAutoScalingGroup -AutoScalingGroupName "{{ environment_name }}-asg v2").Instances | findstr \"InstanceId InService\" 
      $InstanceId=(echo $ASG) | findstr InstanceId 
      $InService=(echo $InstanceId | %{ $_.Split(':')[1]; }).replace(' ','')
    register: InService

note:- using {{ environment_name }} as a variable.
```

CircleCI job failed with below error;

```
amazon-ebs:     "cmd": "$ASG=(Get-ASAutoScalingGroup -AutoScalingGroupName \"dev-asg-v2\").Instances | findstr \"InstanceId InService\" $InstanceId=(echo $ASG) | findstr 'InstanceId' $InService=(echo $InstanceId | %{ $_.Split(':')[1]; }).replace(' ','')",
    amazon-ebs:     "delta": "0:00:12.531289",
    amazon-ebs:     "end": "2020-02-12 12:12:35.640112",
    amazon-ebs:     "msg": "non-zero return code",
    amazon-ebs:     "rc": 1,
    amazon-ebs:     "start": "2020-02-12 12:12:23.108822",
    amazon-ebs:     "stderr": "You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.\r\nAt line:1 char:291\r\n+ ... d' $InService=(echo $InstanceId | %{ $_.Split(':')[1]; }).rep ...\r\n+                                                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\r\n    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException\r\n    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull\r\n \r\nYou cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.\r\nAt line:1 char:65\r\n+ ... ing $false; $ASG=(Get-ASAutoScalingGroup -AutoScalingGroupName \"d ...\r\n+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\r\n    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException\r\n    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull",
    amazon-ebs:     "stderr_lines": [
    amazon-ebs:         "You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.",
    amazon-ebs:         "At line:1 char:291",
    amazon-ebs:         "+ ... d' $InService=(echo $InstanceId | %{ $_.Split(':')[1]; }).rep ...",
    amazon-ebs:         "+                                                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~",
    amazon-ebs:         "    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException",
    amazon-ebs:         "    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull",
    amazon-ebs:         " ",
    amazon-ebs:         "You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.",
    amazon-ebs:         "At line:1 char:65",
    amazon-ebs:         "+ ... ing $false; $ASG=(Get-ASAutoScalingGroup -AutoScalingGroupName \"d ...",
    amazon-ebs:         "+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~",
    amazon-ebs:         "    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException",
    amazon-ebs:         "    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull"
    amazon-ebs:     ],
    amazon-ebs:     "stdout": "",
    amazon-ebs:     "stdout_lines": []
    amazon-ebs: }
```

Answer (score 0):

This usually means the variable you're calling a method on is `null`. Meaning a variable was never set due to an issue with the script

You will be able to debug further by looking at the script you're calling on Ansible around where the error stated it ran into a problem: `At line:1 char:291`. Which seems to be one of these variables:

`$InService=(echo $InstanceId | %{ $_.Split(':')[1]; })`

Try running the script directly on the host to see further.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Well, i tried running all 3 commands locally on server and all of them working as expected.
Am i using the correct syntax while running those commands using ansible win_shell?

Comment: As far as I can see, the syntax is correct. You might want to double check the connection between Ansible (wherever you’re running your playbooks) to that host. Could you expand on further on how everything communicates and where each instance/host is? This would give us a clearer picture of your environment.